# I cannot attribute meaning to symbol ">" in jsFiddle code

Tags: jsfiddle, symbols

I encounter the following code in jsFiddle:

```
$("#start").click(function()
     $("#bg > 
img").addclass('animate');
));
```

What is meaning of > in the second code line?

Comment: `#bg > img`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a [css selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

> is the [child combinator](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) and selects immediate children.

In your example the **img**s that are direct descendants (immediate children) of element with id="**bg**" will be selected.